# CodeIgniter Upload multiple files

Tags: file, codeigniter, upload

CONTROLLER

```
$config['upload_path'] = '../ci/assets/images/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '1000';
$config['max_width'] = '1024'; 
$config['max_height'] = '768';

//load upload library
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

//load mPhoto model
$this->load->model("carstock_model"); 

//Check to see if upload was activated if/then/else statement
if (! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
    $this->load->view('admin_view.php', $error);
} 
else 
{
    for($i=1; $i<6; $i++) {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
        $data2 = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); //returns POST items with XSS filter
        $filename = $data['upload_data']['file_name']; //obtain the upload filename
        $data2['picture' .$i]= $filename .$i; //get and set the filename

        // $data2['PhotoFilenameLarge']=$filename; //get and set the filename
        $this->carstock_model->insertData($data2); //add the db
    }

    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data); //display the success view
}
```

VIEW

```
...    
<input name="userfile" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
...
```

MODEL

```
public function insertData($data){
$this->db->insert("carstock", $data); //active record
}
```

The problem is when passing the files in mysql takes just the last selected image as input and stores the name wrong.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i = 0;$i<=2;$i++){
    $name = 'image_0'.$i;

    if(isset($_FILES[$name])){
        $this->upload->do_upload($name);
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        dump($data['file_name']);
    }else{
        // do nothing
} // end of for loop
```

dump($data['file_name']); will dump file name. But you must select file for every field